# How to get the minutes from two times in java

Tags: java, date, time, date-format

I am trying to get difference between two hours like the following

```java
String time1 = "05:00 AM";
String time2 = "06:20 AM";

String format = "HH:mm aa";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ( format );

Date dateObj1 = null;
Date dateObj2 = null;
try {
    dateObj1 = sdf.parse ( time1 );
    dateObj2 = sdf.parse ( time2 );
} catch ( ParseException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace ( );
}

long diff = dateObj2.getTime ( ) - dateObj1.getTime ( );
double diffInHours = diff / ( ( double ) 1000 * 60 * 60 );
double diffInMins = ( diffInHours + ( int ) diffInHours ) * 60;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "diff: " + diff );
System.out.println ( "diffInHours: " + diffInHours );
System.out.println ( "diffInMins " + diffInMins );
```

When run.

```
diffInHours 1.3333333333333333
Minutes 139.99999999999997
```

I would like to calculate the time in minutes between two times like in the above case i should get 80 minutes but it is giving some other value.

would some one help me to get minutes between two time?

Comment: if you get `diff`(milliseconds) and divide it between 1000, you get seconds, then divide them between 60 and you will get minutes. Anyway, 80 minutes are 4800000 milliseconds, try to print `diff` and check if it matchs.

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8 it could look like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a");
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse(time1, fmt);
LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.parse(time2, fmt);
long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(t1, t2); //80
```

Note that this does not take any DST changes into account.

Comment: Or `t1.until(t2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)`

Answer (score 1):

Result in minutes is just the result in hours multiplied by 60 :

```
System.out.println("Minutes " + (diffInHours)*60 );
```

I don't understand the computation you're doing. If you wanted the rest you should have **removed** the integer part of the hours :

```
System.out.println("Minutes " + (diffInHours - (int)diffInHours)*60 );
```

Which will return 20 (So you have 1 hour and 20 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30260036/642706) by [yannick1976](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520643/yannick1976) is correct. The math in calculating the minutes is incorrect in the Question’s code.

One other error: The formatting **pattern string is apparently incorrect**. The presence of "AM"/"PM" means the `HH` should be `hh` (lowercase). Uppercase `HH` means 24-hour clock whereas `hh` lowercase means 12-hour half-day clock. This error does not affect the given example inputs, but would fail for afternoon/evening inputs.

This Question is yet another example of why one should use a date-time library rather that roll-your-own.

## Joda-Time

I am not clear if the Question was looking for the total elapsed time [a] in  minutes or [b] in hours and minutes where the minutes is the fraction of an hour. The example code below covers both cases.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library provides a `Minutes` class that can calculate total elapsed minutes.

Joad-Time also provides three classes for representing a span of time in various ways: [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html), [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), and [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html).

[`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) represents a pair of points along the timeline. Period turns that into a number of days, hours, and such.

The [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class by defaults creates a String representation in the format specified by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard: [PnYnMnDTnHnMnS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) where `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates the date portion from time portion. So `PT1H20M` is the hour and twenty minutes in our case.

### Example Code

Start with our input strings.

```
String inputStart = "05:00 AM";
String inputStop = "06:20 AM";
```

Those input strings represent time-only, without any date or time zone. So let's parse them as [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) objects.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern ( "hh:mm aa" );
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse ( inputStart, formatter );
LocalTime stopTime = LocalTime.parse ( inputStop, formatter );
```

The `Minutes` class and `Interval`/`Period` classes all require a date-time instance rather than a time-only. So let's convert to a [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), arbitrarily choosing today as the date portion. We assign [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) as the time zone to avoid [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or other anomalies.

```
DateTime start = startTime.toDateTimeToday ( DateTimeZone.UTC );  // Use UTC to avoid DST and other anomalies, as we want general elapsed time rather than on any specific day.
DateTime stop = stopTime.toDateTimeToday ( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Now that we have a pair of [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects, we can use the [`Minutes`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Minutes.html) class’ static method to calculate total elapsed minutes. The `minutesBetween` method returns an object, so we also call `getMinutes` to get simply an `int` number. We expect `80` given our example inputs.

```
int elapsedMinutes = Minutes.minutesBetween ( start, stop ).getMinutes ( );
```

To get hours *and* minutes rather than total minutes, let's define a span of time.

```
Interval interval = new Interval ( start, stop );
Period period = interval.toPeriod ( );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "In UTC, from " + inputStart + " to " + inputStop + " is interval: " + interval + " and period: " + period + ", or " + period.getHours ( ) + " hours and " + period.getMinutes ( ) + " minutes. In total elapsed minutes: " + elapsedMinutes + "." );
```

When run.

```
In UTC, from 05:00 AM to 06:20 AM is interval: 2015-05-15T05:00:00.000Z/2015-05-15T06:20:00.000Z and period: PT1H20M, or 1 hours and 20 minutes. In total elapsed minutes: 80.
```